# Only default url component is loaded in Angular 4/5 after deployment to AWS server

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, angular5, web-deployment

I have deployed an angular 5 app to aws server. Web page is loaded only on default URL. No routing URL works,it throws "The requested URL /routecomponent was not found on this server" error.

```
         { path: '', component: routecomponent } // load this page

         { path: 'home', component: routecomponent } // doesn't load
```

HTACCESS file

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

It demonstrates how to set the `--base-href` to the appropriate folder for routing.